# Converting Visual Basic 6 source code into Java

Tags: java, vb6, converters, code-translation

I have a task to do code-translation of some parts of the application that is written in VB6 into Java. Now, I have two problems, first is that I have never done such a thing, so I'm inexperienced, and second - I never used VB6 before.

I spent some time googling and reading different posts but I couldn't find anything useful so this is my last chance.

Do you know of some tool, converter that could help me with this? If you worked on something like this before, could you give me some advice on how to proceed with this issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I do not think you will be able to find a program that does the conversion for you. Since the languages are very different.
You could always try to convert the code in C# and then in java. But I don't know whether that will be beneficial either.

I would approach this in a completely different manner though. Converting code blindly is not such a good idea. I would try to understand what the code does and try to implement the same thing in my own way and libraries in java.